# IIS / ASP.Net keeps rendering the deleted image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I deleted an image file that stored under the `IIS` default path `wwwroot\`. Then I copied another image file to the same path with the same file name as the deleted one but IIS keeps rendering the deleted image. Why was that? And How to fix the problem?

For example: 
I deleted `Image A`  named `123.jpg` and I copied `Image B` with the same file name `123.jpg` to same folder, while I run the code `<img src="~/images/mc/123.jpg" />`, it keeps return `Image A` instead of `Image B`.

Why was that? And How to fix the problem?

Comment: Try clearing the cache in your browser. Failing that, change the name of the image.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 - The browser will cache images and in some cases when it's been replaced wont appear on a normal refresh (this saves traffic) if the file has been replaced with the same named file this should do the trick.